# What is the difference between Set and List when working with Max function?

Tags: python

Lets say we have a list 
list = [1,1,2,2,3,1]
These 2 lines below give the same output which is the element with most repeated. What is the difference between them? How does the first one work

```
max(set(list),key=list.count) -- output: 1
max(list,key=list.count) -- output: 1
```

Comment: The first will remove duplicates before finding the maximum. But I doubt it is helpfule here.

Comment: how does it find maximum when set will remove all repeated element? and we still using the key=list.count @-@

Comment: Duplicates are not relevant for finding the maximum, but for counting the number of occurrences which is used as the key.

Comment: It is not trying to find the maximum, just finding number of occurrences (my bad, should of been more clear). So my question is, if it is just a set now, which has no duplicate, how does it still able to find it one with most occurrence?

Comment: side-note: Don't name a variable `list`. You are overwriting the reference to the core type `list` by doing that.

Comment: Both of these lines are a bad idea - you should be using `collections.Counter` to avoid quadratic runtime.

Comment: This is not my code. i just found it online. I will use collections.Counter next time Thanks @user2357112,

Answer (score 1):

`max` function iterates over values in its first argument, for each value it calls `key` function, which is in our case `list.count` (number of occurences in **the list**), and at the end returns the value which produced the biggest result.

The first call:
Input is a set: (1, 2, 3)
Corresponding results of `list.count` call are: [3, 2, 1]
And `max` returns 1, since it produced the biggest result (3).

The second call:
Input is a list: [1,1,2,2,3,1]
Corresponding results of `list.count` call are: [3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3]
And again, `max` returns 1, since it produced the biggest result (3).

So, the difference is that in first call `max` has fewer values to iterate over, and therefore fewer `list.count` calls are made. Nonetheless, the result in both cases is the same, because `list.count` calls are done **on the same list**.

And yes, don't name a variable `list`.

Comment: If the input is a set, which has no duplicates. How can list.count still operate on it? They all should have count of 1 right?

Comment: Even if input is set, the call within `max` function is on list. For example for first item, the call is: `[1,1,2,2,3,1].count(1)`, which is 3.